# C2133: Unknown size

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Main class

```
#include "List.h"
#include "Worker.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void initWorkerList(List<Worker>);

int main() {
    List<Worker> WorkerList; // Error highlighted here
    initWorkerList(WorkerList);

    string username, password;
    cout << "Please enter your username: " << endl;
    getline(cin, username);
    cout << "Please enter your password: " << endl;
    getline(cin, password);

    Worker w;
    bool success = w.login(username,password, WorkerList);
    if(success) {
             // code

    } else {
        cout << "Invalid username and/or password. \nPlease try again!";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0; }

void initWorkerList(List<Worker> WorkerList) {
    Worker w1 = Worker("Ben Ang", "Ben123", "pass123", 'M');
    WorkerList.add(w1);
    Worker w2 = Worker("Grace Eng", "Gr4ce", "loveGrace", 'W');
    WorkerList.add(w2);
    Worker w3 = Worker("Rebecca Xuan", "Xuanz", "Rebecca Xuan", 'W');
    WorkerList.add(w3); }
```

Worker class

```
#include <string>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;
class Worker { private:
    string name;
    string username;
    string password;
    char position; public:
    Worker();
    Worker(string, string, string, char);
    string getName();
    string getUserName();
    string getPassword();
    char getPosition();
    bool login(string, string, List<Worker>); };

Worker::Worker() {   }

Worker::Worker(string n, string un, string pw, char p) {
    name = n;
    username = un;
    password = pw;
    position = p; }

string Worker::getName() {
    return name; }

string Worker::getUserName() {
    return username; }

string Worker::getPassword() {
    return password; }

char Worker::getPosition() {
    return position; }

bool login(string username, string password, List<Worker> WorkerList) {
    string u, pw;
    for(int i =0; i<WorkerList.length(); i++) {
        Worker w = WorkerList.get(i);
        u = w.getUserName();
        pw = w.getPassword();
        if(username == u && password == pw) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; }
```

List class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 20;

template <typename ItemType> class List { private:
    ItemType itemList[MAX_SIZE];
    int size; public: 
    List();
    void add(ItemType);
    void del(int index);
    bool isEmpty();
    ItemType get(int);
    int length(); };


template<typename ItemType> List<ItemType>::List() {
    size = 0; }

template<typename ItemType> void List<ItemType>::add(ItemType item) {
    if(size < MAX_SIZE) {
        itemList[size] = item;
        size++; 
    } 
    else {
        cout << "List is full.\n";
    } }

template<typename ItemType> void List<ItemType>::del(int index) {
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        if(index > 0 && index < size) {
            for(int i = index + 1; i <= size; i++) {
                itemList[i-2] = itemList[i-1];
            }
            size--;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "List is empty.\n";
    } }

template<typename ItemType> bool List<ItemType>::isEmpty() {
    return size == 0; }

template<typename ItemType> ItemType List<ItemType>::get(int index) {
    if(index > 0 && index <= size) 
        return itemList[index-1]; }

template<typename ItemType>
int List<ItemType>::length() {
    return size;
}
```

I have many errors but I think this is the cause of the other errors too.

Error 11 error C2133: 'WorkerList' : unknown size

The error is found in the main section. I also do not know why. Previously, it is still workable but this is odd...
So what is wrong with it?

Comment: You forgot to narrow down the problem.

Comment: (You also have a quite strange indentation scheme!)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit meaning?

Answer (score 2):

`login` function in Worker class is a free stand function, you didn't implement `Worker::login`,

change

```
bool login(string username, string password, List<Worker> WorkerList)
```

to

```
bool Worker::login(string username, string password, List<Worker> WorkerList)
```

Also you have multiple `#include List.h"` which generates a few errors indicates multiple definition identifiers in `List.h`, idiomatic way is to provide include guard in header:

for example:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_SIZE 20

// .... other source code

template<typename ItemType>
int List<ItemType>::length() {
    return size;
}

#endif
```

Comment: thanks for helping me in finding an error! :)

Comment: include guard should fix most of errors and fix login, your compiles fine

Comment: means to be on the safe side. Should I include this for all my XXX.h so that I won't get this error?

Comment: YEP! It did fix most of my errors and login too. Only left Error MAX_SIZE' : redefinition; different storage class

Comment: you should define include guard in all header files. could use #define for max_size

Comment: Meaning? I have tried Maciej Stachowski's tips by adding "#define MAX_SIZE 20" inside but I got more errors cause I didn't learn until that so did I do something wrongly?

Comment: should put define outside class, see my updated answer for define sample

Comment: I did as you said but I am still getting many unknown errors..and I have a qsn too, is there a ; after #define MAX_SIZE = 20?

Comment: my apologize, should be `#define MAX_SIZE 20`

Comment: Oops. Should be apologizing instead. I copied the wrong one instead..Why is the semi-colon not needed? And why is it #define? How to use? Is there any guides? Sorry again..

Comment: have a read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/ and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

Comment: THANKS LOADS FOR THE GUIDE!!!! I will read it now! :DD

Answer (score 2):

```
ItemType itemList[MAX_SIZE];
```

I think there is your problem. Consider replacing it with a dynamically allocated array, or replacing `const int MAX_SIZE = 20;` with a `#define`.

Comment: meaning? Is there any examples?

Comment: Wait, you know templates, but don't know how to dynamically allocate an array? `#define MAX_SIZE 20` should work. As for dynamically-allocated arrays, just Google a tutorial.

By the way, I've checked the code and it doesn't give me any errors. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sad but true. I have only learnt the very basics of templates. I have added #define MAX_SIZE 20 but it gave me more unknown errors than before.. :X

Comment: You have removed the `const int MAX_SIZE = 20` line, right? And added the header guards?

Comment: I don't really know which compiler it is. You mean compiler meaning Visual Studio compiler? Or C++ compiler?

Comment: I removed as you said..AND IT WORKS! hahas. I've included the header guards too alr. THANKS LOADS!!!

Answer (score 2):

When I add multiple inclusion guards to the headers, then the only compilation warning I get from g++ (G++ 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5) is:

```
$ g++ -O3 -g -I/Users/jleffler/inc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -c so14299529.cpp
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h: In member function ‘ItemType List<ItemType>::get(int) [with ItemType = Worker]’:
List.h:49:35: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
$
```

Without the header guards, I get a lot of errors, such as:

```
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:7:11: error: redefinition of ‘const int MAX_SIZE’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:7:11: error: ‘const int MAX_SIZE’ previously defined here
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:9:36: error: redefinition of ‘class List<ItemType>’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:9:36: error: previous definition of ‘class List<ItemType>’
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:20:29: error: redefinition of ‘List<ItemType>::List()’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:20:29: error: ‘List<ItemType>::List()’ previously declared here
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:23:34: error: redefinition of ‘void List<ItemType>::add(ItemType)’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:23:34: error: ‘void List<ItemType>::add(ItemType)’ previously declared here
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:32:34: error: redefinition of ‘void List<ItemType>::del(int)’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:32:34: error: ‘void List<ItemType>::del(int)’ previously declared here
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:44:34: error: redefinition of ‘bool List<ItemType>::isEmpty()’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:44:34: error: ‘bool List<ItemType>::isEmpty()’ previously declared here
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:47:38: error: redefinition of ‘ItemType List<ItemType>::get(int)’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:47:38: error: ‘ItemType List<ItemType>::get(int)’ previously declared here
In file included from Worker.h:6:0,
                 from so14299529.cpp:2:
List.h:52:5: error: redefinition of ‘int List<ItemType>::length()’
In file included from so14299529.cpp:1:0:
List.h:52:5: error: ‘int List<ItemType>::length()’ previously declared here
List.h: In member function ‘ItemType List<ItemType>::get(int) [with ItemType = Worker]’:
List.h:49:35: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

The header guards are a simple, reliable technique to ensure that a header is not included more than once, because that typically leads to problems like those shown.

Hence, IMO, the appropriate fix is to add a couple of lines to the top and one line at the bottom of each header, such as shown below.

#### List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

... Original content of header ...

#endif /* LIST_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### Worker.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H_INCLUDED
#define WORKER_H_INCLUDED

... Original content of header ...

#endif /* WORKER_H_INCLUDED */
```

You can have comments before the header guard, but nothing else; all the operational code should be inside the header guards.

Comment: ??? Meaning? I have shown #include "Worker.h" in my main source file alr. Unless I have misunderstood what you were saying. :X

Comment: @unknown: It appears I miscopied the code in the question; I've significantly changed my answer.

Comment: ohh. Scared me just now when i thought i didn't add the "Worker.h". Hahahs. THANKS! It did solve all of my errors except the MAX_SIZE part. I'm currently still figuring it out..